# conditions on count column using counter catch rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Relations:

vote.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :celebrity, counter_cache: true
```

celebrity.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :category
has_many :votes
```

I need to use conditions in vote model something like

```
belongs_to :celebrity, counter_cache: true, :conditions => ['votes.upvote = ? ', true]
```

can anyone help me here

Comment: hey you can refer this link for conditions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156514/what-is-the-purpose-of-conditions-on-a-belongs-to-association

Answer (score 1):

You can read [this](http://douglasfshearer.com/2006/10/06/custom-counter-cache-with-conditions.html) article, which basically recommends adding a new column (for value with condition) in parent object and update it whenever child model is changed.

You can also use the [counter_culture](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture) gem, which is built around the same idea, but has more functionality built in.

Comment: http://pastie.org/10409446 Do you think it will help me ? do I need to remove votes_count column in celebrity table?